# Checking the gigantic unformatted file generated in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

The output of my fortran program is a gigantic (300GB) unformatted file. ( In fact, this file includes the time evolution of the xyz coordinates of many many particles. So, the data type is real*8, if it matters at all)

The problem is that I am not sure if all of those data were written correctly, because of a transient issue in the computational server. Now, im left with this gigantic file, and looking for a way to check if all of its content are healthy!

Is there a way to check weather all of the xyz's are written correctly, and not corruptedly (say like NaN)?

Comment: NaN by definition cannot be equal to anything, including itself, so a quick nan check is `var /= var`.

Comment: You could use `grep`...

Comment: grep ?!!!! for a 300GB file having millions of records?!! and then manually check with my eyes staring to the monitor to see if those millions of numbers are all correct!!!!

Comment: If you grep for NaNs, there should be no output if all is correct...

Comment: yes; but this is an unformatted file. If I want to use grep, first I have to convert it to decimal text file. This will generate a txt file of the order of at least 3X300GB~1TB. grep will take forever, if the system not freeze!  Does it make sense?

Comment: Assuming you have a terabyte of hard drive available, you could break it into several smaller chunks. You might be able to rig it up to run in parallel too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to dwwork's method of checking for NaNs, you can also check for infinity.  After that, it is a simple matter of reading the file and looping through every value.  Since you wrote the file, I assume that you can read it.

```
  program testinfnan

  implicit none

  real*8 :: x, y, z

  logical :: xnan, ynan, znan, xinf, yinf, zinf

  z = 1.
  x = z / 0.
  y = x / x 

  print *, ''
  print *, 'x = ', x
  print *, 'y = ', y
  print *, 'z = ', z

  xnan = x /= x
  ynan = y /= y
  znan = z /= z

  print *, ''
  print *, 'xnan = ', xnan
  print *, 'ynan = ', ynan
  print *, 'znan = ', znan

  xinf = x == 1./0
  yinf = y == 1./0
  zinf = z == 1./0

  print *, ''
  print *, 'xinf = ', xinf
  print *, 'yinf = ', yinf
  print *, 'zinf = ', zinf

  end program testinfnan
```

Output:

```
x =                 Infinity
y =                      NaN 
z =    1.00000000000000    

xnan =  F
ynan =  T
znan =  F

xinf =  T
yinf =  F
zinf =  F
```

Comment: With a Fortran 2003 compliant compiler the intrinsic `ieee_is_nan` function might be a better tool for detecting `NaNs`.  Likewise `ieee_is_finite` for detecting infinities.

Comment: thank you! actually, the key was what dwwork told: "NaN by definition cannot be equal to anything, including itself..." . Also what you mentioned is important; looking for inf numbers. I checked them out and there are bunch of NaN and inf records...